# apt not found when I use apt in gitlab ci before_script

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I use gitlab ci to build docker image and I want to install python. When I build, the following is my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: docker:stable
stages:
  - test
  - build

before-script:
  - apt install -y python-dev python pip

test1:
  stage: test
  script:
  ...
    - pytest

build:
  stage: build
  - docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG .
  - docker push $IMAGE_TAG
```

but i got a Job failed

```
/bin/sh: eval: line : apt: not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

I also tried to apt-get install but the result is the same.

How do I install python??

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's actually not a problem but you can say it featured by package-manager with Alpine you are using image: docker:stable or any such images like tomcat or Django they are on Alpine Linux. with minimal in the size .

```
image: docker:stable
stages:
 - test
 - build

before-script:
 - apk add python python-dev python pip

test1:
stage: test
script:
...
- pytest

build:
stage: build
 - docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG .
 - docker push $IMAGE_TAG
```

apk is Alpine Linux package management

Answer (score 10):

The image that you are using docker: stable is based on [Alpine Linux](https://alpinelinux.org) which uses `apk` as its package manager.  installation with `apk` will look like that: `apk add python`

Answer (score 10):

The error you see is because apt doesn’t exist in alpine docker.

This line solved the problem for me:

`apk update && apk add python`